# Get all meshes in world space in react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm pretty new to using React three fiber but I'm trying to create an outer box and have a bunch of inner boxes drop into the outer box.  I'm using a back end bin packing library that gives the coordinates but the library has no concept of local and world space.  So the coords it gives is basically all in world space.  The issue is I'm mapping the list of inner boxes and its doing the parent of the mesh just rendered is the previous mesh rendered rather than having the Canvas as the parent.
So like box1 is parent of box2 and box2 is parent of box3 and so forth.  I want everything to have the Canvas as the parent.  I'm not sure how to do this using three fiber
This is the main component where the outer box is PackingBox  and the inner boxes are ItemBoxes

```
export const BinPacker = () => {
  const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);

  // test item coordinates
  const positions = useMemo(() => [
    [0, -0.2, 0],
    // [1, 0, 0],
    // [1, 0, 0.6],
    // [0.4, 0, 1],
    // [0, 0, 1],
    // [1, 0, 1.1],
    // [0, 1, 0],

  ], []);
  // test item dimensions
  const packages = useMemo(() => [
    [1, 1, 1],
    // [0.3, 0.9, 0.6],
    // [0.3, 0.8, 0.5],
    // [0.6, 0.7, 0.3],
    // [0.4, 0.6, 0.2],
    // [0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
    // [0.7, 0.3, 0.5],
  ], []);
  const positionsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(positions));
  const startingPositions = positionsCopy.map(pos => [pos[0], pos[1] += 3, pos[2]]);
  const [startPosition, setStartPosition] = useState(startingPositions);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setStartPosition(startingPositions);
    setAnimate(true);
  }, [startingPositions]);


  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </Button>
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [3, 3, 3], fov: 50 }}>
        <group position={[0, 0, 0]}>
          <PackingBox />
          {positions.map((pos, index) => {
            return (
              <ItemBoxes key={pos} animate={animate} position={pos} setAnimate={setAnimate} setStartPosition={setStartPosition} size={packages[index]}startingPosition={startPosition[index]} />
            );
          })}
        </group>

        <OrbitControls />
      </Canvas>
    </>

  );
};
```

And this is the inner box component-

```
export const ItemBoxes = ({
  position, animate, startingPosition, setAnimate, setStartPosition, size,
}) => {
  const ref = useRef();


  useFrame((_, delta) => {
    if (animate) {
      if (ref.current.position.y > position[1]) {
        ref.current.position.y -= 1 * delta;
      }
      if (ref.current.position.y <= position[1]) {
        setAnimate(false);
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <mesh ref={ref} position={startingPosition}>
      <boxGeometry args={size} attach='geometry' />
      <meshBasicMaterial attach='material-0' color='#ff99ff' opacity={0.6} transparent />
      <meshBasicMaterial attach='material-2' color='#99ccff' opacity={0.6} transparent />
      <meshBasicMaterial attach='material-4' color='#ff6699' opacity={0.6} transparent />
      <Edges
        color='grey'
        scale={1}
        threshold={15} // Display edges only when the angle between two faces exceeds this value (default=15 degrees)
      />
    </mesh>);
};
```